# Inserting string which contain single quotes ' in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-injection

I've seen so many solutions to this that I don't know which one to follow.
I thought that what I have would work but upon further testing I have discovered that this is not true.
I'm using VB to pick up MS Excel worksheets from a given file directory, extract the data, and insert into SQL data tables.

here's the part I need some help with:

```
 If saRet(linex, 11) <> "" Then
 IntDesc = (saRet(linex, 11).ToString.Replace("'", "''"))
 Echo("Internal description: " & IntDesc)
        Else
           Echo("No internal description given")
           IntDesc = ""
 End If
```

After tampering around with some test insert statements in SQL server studio I thought that replacing ' with  '' worked. Sadly, not.

Here's an example of a string which makes the insert fail:

```
Set-up and Config of New Button on BP and UDF's for Despatch Process
```

and after my string manipulation, here's the Insert statement(I've blanked out some data which my company probably doesn't want to share, it's insignificant anyway):

```
NSERT INTO <tablename> VALUES ('2013-12-10', '12', '2013', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', '10668', 'JBT', 'Project - Config & System Build', 'CSB', '2', 'Y', 'N', '0', 'Set-up and Config of New Button on BP and UDF's for Despatch Process', 'Set-up and Config of New Button on BP and UDF''s for Despatch Process', '0', 'NULL')
```

Very grateful for any help!
Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The SQL tag is not for SQL Server.  This question has nothing to do with VB6, Excel, or VB.Net.  Very poorly tagged.

Comment: @Bob77 Considering it's VB code in the example provided, and some people writing similar EXCEL extraction code in VB may have the same problem, I think the tags are appropriate. Congrats on wasting both of our time with that comment.

Comment: I've fixed your tags for you to be appropriate to what you are asking and what technologies are *actually involved in your question*. Please do not add in the tags 'excel' or 'vb6' back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is always using parameters. Those handle everything for you and you don't need to do any escaping.

If you can't use parameters, you have to do the encoding yourself, and that's very tricky. One way would be to use a format you can encode safely - for example, instead of inserting as a string literal, you might use binary encoding (eg. `cast(0xAABBCCDD as varchar(max))`). This is perfectly safe, since you can be sure that there's no invalid character that would break it. Of course, it also has its problems.

As for your example, replacing `'` with `''` works fine (although of course you'd have to watch out for other invalid characters, such as endlines). Your problem is that you didn't do the encoding on *all* the strings. In your sample, the last string has the proper encoding, the one before it does not. This also beautifully illustrates the pain of making sure you're encoding properly - and everything you miss means an error, or even a way to exploit the code and cause harm. For example, what if the description was `', ''0'', ''NULL''); delete from users --`?

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll have a look around for some documentation on this. You mentioned binary encoding then provided an example which looked like Hex?

Comment: @Cal Yeah, I've written it in hexadecimal notation, but it's a binary literal. Don't dwell on this, it's just naming. Simply go character by character (if there's no simpler way) and convert it from char to byte, and write that in 2-digit hexadecimal (for example `byte.ToString("X2")` in C#).